# How to write test case for string array input in junit?(new to junit)

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am new to junit and trying out to write 2 test cases for my program, but unable to execute it as it keep saying argument type mismatch.
Just have look on the code and if possible please let me know the proper solution.
I have tried the same way for simple variable and its working, but for string array its not working.

Logic class :
Here I am trying to push each letter of the string in the stack.

```
public class myClass{   

protected double myLogic(String[] exp) {
    Stack<Double> s = new Stack<Double>();
    String[] expArr = null;
    for (int j = 0; j < exp.length; j++) {
        expArr = exp[j].split("\\s");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < expArr.length; i++) {

        if (expArr[i].matches("[0-9]+") || expArr[i].matches("[0-9].+")) {
            s.push(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(expArr[i])));
        }

}
 return s.pop();
}
```

and this is my Junit test class:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTestCasess {

public String[] exp=null;
public Double[] pfResult = { 3, 3 };

public MyTestCasess(String[] exp1) {

    for(int i=0;i<exp1.length;i++){
        exp[i]=exp1[i];
    }
}

@Parameters
public static List<String> data() {
    String[] data = { "1 2 3", "6 2 3" };
    return Arrays.asList(data);
}

@Test
public void testMainCaller() {
    myClass objExp = new myClass();     
    Assert.assertEquals("Result", pfResult, objExp.myLogic(exp));

}

}
```

Log error message :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.createTestUsingConstructorInjection(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.parameterized.BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParameters.java:38)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Please add the error  / log message as well to the post...

Comment: There are no error log, the code is working fine when the string input is taken from the console. But by using Junit test cases it fails. I may be not implementing the Junit test cases properly. The error in Junit tab is "Argument mismatch"

Comment: Please try to run the build on command line via `mvn clean package`...

Comment: I have tried but found no luck yet..! I have added the error log for your reference, please see and let me know if you have any suggestions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `data()` provides a list of `String`s. This means that each of your parameter sets is a single `String`. Unfortunately your test class constructor expects a `String` array instead of a single `String`. This is why your test is failing.

Comment: So you are saying, I should declare two separate string variables and then proceed with the test cases?